# What kind of validation should I do for post content in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I'm working on a CMS in Codeigniter and I'm currently setting up some validation rules for all my fields.

I have XSS filtering and CSRF protection enabled. I'm also using active records.

The content field allows HTML characters but I don't want JS/PHP code to execute (XSS filtering will prevent this?).

With the protections I currently have set up, is there anything I'm still susceptible to? What precautions should I take? What validation rules should I be employing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI's XSS filter misses Javascript events when they are not inside script tags. I don't suggest that you turn off the filter, but additionally you should encode the data, at least with the PHP built-in functions, right after input, and decode right before output.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to write a custom callback function to strip off php/js tags.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: Doesn't XSS filtering encode PHP tags? Or is that not enough?